# How to return an ActiveRecord relation through two other has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests, class_name: 'Story', foreign_key: 'requester_id'
  has_many :ownerships, class_name: 'Story', foreign_key: 'owner_id'

  def stories
    requests | ownerships
  end
end
```

In this case the method `stories` will return an array of uniq objects as I want. But I'll need to use something like `User.first.stories.where("title = 'foo'")` that returns an error, because it's an array, not a relation.

So what can I do to get this same results through relation allowing to use with Arel?

PS.: Im on Rails 3.1.rc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def stories
    Story.where "(owner_id = :id) OR (requester_id = :id)", :id => id
  end
end
```

or this could be written even nicer if you use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)

```
def stories
  Story.where { (owner_id == my{id}) | (requester_id == my{id}) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a scope returns a relation. Transforming the method as LOJ scope should help I guess.

```
scope :stories, select('stories.*').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN stories ON 
users.id = stories.requester_id LEFT OUTER JOIN stories ON users.id = stories.owner_id')
```